# js alert keep looping for no reasons

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an async function that on page load it runs a function that gets a JSON file and stores it in songResults. it then gets a random object from the JSON and takes some parameters from it and uses them to set the sources for some elements in my HTML file. it then wait for the user to input text on the site and wait for them to click the submit button, the guessingGame() functions runs fine the first time but the second time when you guess the answer correct it alerts to it being wrong, and loops a couple times then says it was correct. it gets worse the more time you get it correct. I have no idea what is causing this

JS code

```
const onPageLoad = async () => {
  let songResults = await getSongData();
  let randomSong = songResults[Math.floor(Math.random() * songResults.length)];
  audioSound.src = randomSong.song_path;
  audioSound.load();
  albumCover.src = randomSong.photo_path;
  //An event listener for the submit button to run the guessing game function.
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    guessingGame(randomSong.song_name);
});
};

//async function for when the button is clicked to check the answer in the input box to the json data.
const guessingGame = async (songName) => {
  //get the value of the input box
  let input = document.getElementById("guessInputBox").value;
  //check if the value of the input box matches the song path in the json data
  if (input) {
    if (input.toLowerCase() === songName.toLowerCase()) {
        alert('correct');
        score++;
        alert("that took " + score + " attempts");
        score = 0;
        onPageLoad();
    } else {
        alert('incorrect');
        alert(songName);
        score++;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: `submitButton.addEventListener("click", guessingGame(randomSong.song_path))` - you are not adding `guessingGame` as the event callback here, you are _calling_ the function.

Comment: sorry i added the old code i updated it, i had that issue before and switched it to a function, but it makes the alert bugout

Comment: `guessingGame` calls `onPageLoad`, so on each run you are adding _another_ click handler ...

Comment: i tried added a removeEventListener in the if statement of guessing game but it doesn't remove the handler.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, your `guessingGame` and `onPageLoad` functions both call each other, meaning your code will continue to add event listeners to your submit button.

Removing event listeners can be tricky, specifically with functions that use parameters. Thankfully, there is something called an `AbortController` which can be passed in as an option when you add an event listener. This will allow you to remove a specific instance of an event that was added.

```js
const onPageLoad = async () => {
  let songResults = await getSongData();
  let randomSong = songResults[Math.floor(Math.random() * songResults.length)];
  audioSound.src = randomSong.song_path;
  audioSound.load();
  albumCover.src = randomSong.photo_path;
  //An event listener for the submit button to run the guessing game function.
  const abortCont = new AbortController(); // Create the AbortController
  submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    guessingGame(randomSong.song_name, abortCont);
  }, { signal: abortCont.signal }); // Pass the AbortController in
};

//async function for when the button is clicked to check the answer in the input box to the json data.
const guessingGame = async (songName, abortCont) => {
  //get the value of the input box
  let input = document.getElementById("guessInputBox").value;
  //check if the value of the input box matches the song path in the json data
  if (input) {
    if (input.toLowerCase() === songName.toLowerCase()) {
        alert('correct');
        score++;
        alert("that took " + score + " attempts");
        score = 0;
        abortCont.abort(); // Remove the event listener
        onPageLoad();
    } else {
        alert('incorrect');
        alert(songName);
        score++;
    }
  }
};
```